# I can't insert data of select from modal?

Tags: php, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I tried to do the same for the input but With no chance however I did not understand if I has to be done with the change function should it be  inserted seperately from the rest of the rest of the modal data

---

```
<select class="form-select form-select-lg mb-3" aria-label=".form-select-lg example" name="TypeCo" id="TypeCo">
                                        <option selected name="TypeCo" id="TypeCo">Type de concentrateur</option>
                                        <option value="Concentrateur Fixe">Concentrateur Fixe</option>
                                        <option value="Concentrateur transportable">Concentrateur transportable</option>


                                    </select>
                                    <select class="form-select form-select-lg mb-3" aria-label=".form-select-lg example" name="CapCo">
                                        <option selected name="CapCo" id="CapCo">Capacité de concentrateur</option>
                                        <option value="5L">5L</option>
                                        <option value="7L">7L</option>
                                        <option value="10L">10L</option>
                                        <option value="15L">15L</option>

                                    </select>
```

### and here is my script

```
    $(document).ready(function() {


            $(document).on('click', '#save', function() {
                var fname = $('#fname').val();
                var lname = $('#lname').val();
                var tel = $('#tel').val();
                var email = $('#email').val();
                var TypeCo = $('#TypeCo').val();
                var CapC = $('#CapCo').val();
                alert(fname + lname + tel + email + TypeCo);

                $.ajax({

                    url: "insert.php",
                    type: "post",
                    data: {
                        fname: fname,
                        lname: lname,
                        email: email,
                        tel: tel,
                        TypeCo: TypeCo,
                        CapCo = CapCo
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        $("#save").modal('hide');
                        alert('jj');
                        location.reload();
                    }
                });

            });
        });
```

---

any help please ? it's my first project with ajax and I cannot really find a vid that can help me

Comment: The `name` and `id` should be on the `<select>`, not on an `<option>` element.  You want the value *of the `<select>`*.

Comment: & then  FOR GETTING THE VALUE OF THE  select the script how it should be if u got an example of a modal like this

Comment: You appear to be using jQuery.  To get the value of a `<select>` you would use `.val()` like any other form element.  The problem in the code shown appears to be little more than a typo, you're just targeting the wrong element in your selectors.  You want to get the value from the `<select>` element, not the `<option>` element.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed how you get the value from a form element in jQuery:

```
var TypeCo = $('#TypeCo').val();
```

*However*, you are targeting the wrong element.  `#TypeCo` is currently targeting an `<option>` element:

```
<option selected name="TypeCo" id="TypeCo">Type de concentrateur</option>
```

You want to get the value *of the `<select>` element itself* (which contains `<option>` elements for the user to select that value).  Move the `name` and `id` there:

```
<select class="form-select form-select-lg mb-3" aria-label=".form-select-lg example" name="TypeCo" id="TypeCo">
    <option selected>Type de concentrateur</option>
    <option value="Concentrateur Fixe">Concentrateur Fixe</option>
    <option value="Concentrateur transportable">Concentrateur transportable</option>
</select>
```

Then you can use `.val()` exactly like you already do:

```js
$('#TypeCo').on('change', function () {
  let value = $('#TypeCo').val();
  console.log(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-select form-select-lg mb-3" aria-label=".form-select-lg example" name="TypeCo" id="TypeCo">
    <option selected>Type de concentrateur</option>
    <option value="Concentrateur Fixe">Concentrateur Fixe</option>
    <option value="Concentrateur transportable">Concentrateur transportable</option>
</select>
```